# Minted: won't break page

Tags: listings, minted, code

This is example of my problem.
This picture shows the end of the page

[image]

This is my code

```
 begin{listing}[ht!]
\begin{minted}
[style=colorful,
breaklines=true]
{java}
//code...
public class Document {
    int num;

//a lot of lines code...

\end{minted}
\caption{Code}
\label{listing:1}
\end{listing}
```

i removed {listing}, and lines now don't always broke

[image]

here is my new code

```
\begin{minted}
[style=colorful,
breaklines=true]
{java}
//code....
\end{minted}
\caption{My Code}
\label{listing:1}
```

Comment: a `minted` environment would break but `listing` is a float and floats (like `figure and `table`) are boxes that never break over a page.

Comment: i removed the begining and end of {listing} , now the line won't break

Comment: please edit your example to be a complete small document that shows the  problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please provide the `MWE` in error free format and it should be from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` ...